# ASP.NET MVC - Invalid assignment left-hand side when trying to use C# inside JS function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a View where I would like to pass some values to my Session. To achieve this, I've created a JS function called whenever I click to a specific button. This function receives an index number as a parameter and retrieves the relative object from the model passed to the view and its own quantity selected from an option list in the viewpage, assigning both to the Session. The problem I'm facing is I can't figure out how to mix Javascript and C# correctly. In the current situation I'm receiving the following error from the console:

> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Which refers to the following HTML generated by the application:

```
 function setItemToSession(index) {

        '0' = index;
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById(("quantitySelection" + index)).nodeValue;
        var itemSelected = B2BCommerceThesis.Models.ViewModels.ShoppingItem;
        '' = itemSelected;
        '' = selectedValue;


        alert("Everything works great with index: " + index);
        return;
    }
```

The relative code inside the view is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setItemToSession(index) {

            @indexSelected = index;
            var selectedValue = document.getElementById(("quantitySelection" + index)).nodeValue;
            var itemSelected = @Model.shoppingItems[indexSelected];
            '@Session["ShoppingCart"]' = itemSelected;
            '@Session["itemQuantities"]' = selectedValue;


            alert("Everything works great with index: " + index);
            return;
        }


    </script>
```

Where `indexSelected` is a global variabile defined at the begin of the .cshtml.
I know it's a dumb question, but I can't find a standard practice which handles this problem efficently. How can I resolve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't assign/update `Session` in JavaScript. Create a ajax request

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change serverside session's in JavaScript on the client, that is not possible.

If you want to change the session you need to make an MVC or WebApi call or keep your data in the client's localStorage

Comment: Oh you are right, I'll use a WebApi Call passing the selected product and then I'll refresh the product list with the shopping cart updated.

Comment: or you can use hidden field to maintain the value instead of '@indexSelected = index;' you can use $('#hiddenFildId').val(index);

Comment: @RKSharma Yeah this also a good solution, I'll mantain the items id with its quantity and whenever I want to access the shopping cart I'll retrieve them from the database. Thank you!